# Issue with clojure macro returning map with java object

Tags: macros, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm very new to macros so I have a basic question that seems to do with the way that Java objects are represented in Clojure code. I have a macro that should return a map:

```
(defmacro g []
  (let [m {:color :black}]
     `(identity ~m)))


user=> (g)
{:color :black}
```

However when I use a java object in the map, things get weird

```
(defmacro g []
  (let [m {:color java.awt.Color/BLACK}]
     `(identity ~m)))

 user=> (g)
 CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't embed object in code, maybe
 print-dup not defined: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0], compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1
 :1)
```

If I change `defmacro` to `defn` the output looks like this:

```
user=> (g)
(clojure.core/identity {:color #<Color java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]>})
```

So I'm guessing the representation is borking up the reader. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to write this though one way that strikes me as appropriately macro-ish is to have it return a form that evaluates to the map including the `let`.

```
user> (defmacro g []
          `(let [m# {:color java.awt.Color/BLACK}]
                 (identity m#)))
#'user/g
user> (g)
{:color #<Color java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]>}
```

This allows the object to be resolved from the class.

Comment: This doesn't change when the object is "resolved", in the sense of namespaces: the resolution is all done at read-time, in the namespace in which the macro is defined. The difference is that the macro, rather than in some magical way *including* "the color black" as though I had typed the idea of blackness in as source code, produces code that looks up `BLACK` as a static field in the class `java.awt.Color` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when your macro is expanded.

```
(macroexpand '(g))
;=> (clojure.core/identity {:color #<Color java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]>})
```

Notice how the Java object is not in a readable form?

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler prints and re-reads the forms between cycles of evaluation?

Comment: Why else would this fail? (I'm curious.) The error messages mentions that `print-dup` may not be defined for the object.

Comment: Hmm, well I implemented `print-dup` for `java.awt.Color` and it doesn't appear to use it when printing the expanded macro.